# Как спарсить текст со всеми переносами и размером шрифтов?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Я делаю парсер сайта с определенными товарами. мне нужно выгрузить с этого сайта все товары с их ценами, названиями, картинками и описанием, но описание парсится без переносов и размеров шрифта. Можно ли как нибудь спарсить описание с переносами и размером шрифтов. Выгружаю я всю спарсенную информацию в формат csv.

Вот мне нужно выгрузить так же как на скрине:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сохраняйте просто блок и все, если хотите такую же разметку

Comment: Для правильной интерпретации переносов используйте html2text.

Comment: А вот со шрифтами сложнее - они ведь могут находиться в файлах стилей. Тут нужен браузерный движок + прослойка типа Selenium.